# how to pass html table data value but not included the 1st row of the table as a json stringify object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i wanna to ask.
how to pass the html table value into a `json stringify` object?
i have made a code and i try to run it and didn't going well.
maybe i have wrong syntax in my code there. bellow is my code that i have try to make so far. i don't know why it not working, please help me. i am a newbie that want to try to know something new

```js
// JavaScript Docume
$(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
    var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            var rows = [];
            $('.table-bordered tr').each(function(i, n){
                var $row = $(n);
                rows.push({
                    $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(6)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(7)').text(),
                });
            });
            return JSON.stringify(rows);
        };
    $(function(){        
       console.log(convertTableToJson ());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Kode Material</th>
<th>Storage Location</th>
<th>Movement Type</th>
<th>Id Indentifier</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Date Input</th>
<th>Netto</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1" name="mycheckbox1"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>101200</td>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006540050</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>23.970</td>
<td>KG</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>101200</td>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006539985</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>42.970</td>
<td>KG</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

maybe someone can help me . i would appreciated when give me an example and give me a reason why my code not work.

this is my code

Comment: Replace braces `{}` with brackets `[]` in `rows.push(...)`

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude im still get the 1st row.
how to make it to not select the 1st row in the array

Comment: when i try to put the `i` element at `for` function will give me some error on my code

Comment: @MinervazMine check my answer. This should be exactly what you expecting.

Comment: @AKA with the replacement brackets from timothe advice.
i can get the array. but still the 1st array still on my array

Comment: It should work fine.

Comment: Check my answer, you will find it appropriate.

Comment: @AKA with your code the data of my table will be separate with the element of the `header`

Comment: You can replace the jQuery selector with `$('.table-bordered tr:has(td)')` to skip the first line.

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude i try to change my selector with ` $('.table-bordered tr:has(td)')` still get the data of index [0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `map().get()` function of `jquery` .Object need a key value pair. so  add `key` with `th` element text

**updated**

```js
// JavaScript Docume
$(document).on('click', '#display_data', function(e) {
  var h = $('.table-bordered tr th')
  var convertTableToJson = function() {
    var rows = $('.table-bordered tbody tr').map(function(i, n) {
      var obj = {};
      $(this).find('td').each(function(k) {
        obj[h.eq(k).text()] = $(this).text();
      })
      return obj;
    }).get();

    return JSON.stringify(rows);
  };

  $(function() {
    console.log(convertTableToJson());
    console.log(JSON.parse(convertTableToJson()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Kode Material</th>
      <th>Storage Location</th>
      <th>Movement Type</th>
      <th>Id Indentifier</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Date Input</th>
      <th>Netto</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1" name="mycheckbox1"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>101200</td>
      <td>WCB</td>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>5006540050</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10.08.2017</td>
      <td>23.970</td>
      <td>KG</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2323</td>
      <td>WssdCB</td>
      <td>1013</td>
      <td>50036539985</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>103.08.2017</td>
      <td>423.970</td>
      <td>KGD</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="display_data">display_data</button>
```

Comment: nah this is that what i need

Comment: can you explain to me.

Comment: `[i]: $(n).find('td').map(function(k, l) {
          return $(l).text();` give me an error on my page why like that

Comment: I think it has some variable declaration problem. Try with my updated answer @MinervazMine

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need.

```js
$(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
    var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            var headings = [];
            var rows = [];
            $('.table-bordered tr').each(function(i, n){
               //for table header
               if(i==0){
                 $(n).find('th').each(function(){
                     if($(this).text()!==''){
                        headings.push($(this).text());
                     }
                  })
               }
               //for table data
               else{
                  var obj = {};
                  $(n).find('td').each(function(index){
                    if($(this).text()!==''){
                       obj[headings[index]] = $(this).text();
                    }
                  });
                  rows.push(obj);
               }
            });
            return JSON.stringify(rows);
        };
    $(function(){        
       console.log(convertTableToJson ());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Kode Material</th>
<th>Storage Location</th>
<th>Movement Type</th>
<th>Id Indentifier</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Date Input</th>
<th>Netto</th>
<th>Unit</th>
<th><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox1" name="mycheckbox1"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>101200</td>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006540050</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>23.970</td>
<td>KG</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>101200</td>
<td>WCB</td>
<td>101</td>
<td>5006539985</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>10.08.2017</td>
<td>42.970</td>
<td>KG</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id='display_data'>Click me </button>
```

Observe that the last column with no heading is not included and each JSON object contains the key as column heading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
function convertTableToJson()
    {
        var rows = new Object();
        var th = [];
        $('tr th').each(function() {
            th.push($(this).text());
        })
        $('.table-bordered tbody tr').each(function(i, n){
                rows["row"+i] = new Object();
            $(this).find('td').each(function(index,ele){
                var head = th[index];
              rows["row"+i][head]= $(this).text();
            })
        });
        return JSON.stringify(rows);
    }

   console.log(convertTableToJson ()); 
});
```

See the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a4og6y63/1)